# Mockito/Mockk verify call paramether

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, mockk

I'd like to know if is possible test with mockito/mockk this situation:
Im trying to test method "Test.doSomething()" inside this, has a method call to another class like "Test2.doAnotherThing(parameterObject)" . And I'd like to use mockito.verify to test "Test2.doAnotherThing(parameterObject)"  but I need verify if parameterObject atributes are correct. This parameterObject is created inside of "Test.doSomething()" soo I'm using "any()" to use 'verify'.

Comment: Mockk solution: https://notwoods.github.io/mockk-guidebook/docs/matching/with/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use an [ArgumentCaptor](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argumentcaptor) as follows:

```java
ArgumentCaptor<ParameterObjectClass> parameterObjectCaptor = 
      ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ParameterObjectClass.class);
verify(Test2, times(1)).doAnotherThing(parameterObjectCaptor.capture());
assertThat(parameterObjectCaptor.getValue())....
```